# libwebsockets: which library does the type Client belong to?

Tags: c, websocket, client, libwebsockets

I am currently building a WebSocket server and I came across the following code to handle fragmented messages (from [libwebsockets](https://github.com/davidgaleano/libwebsockets/blob/6ce62c03f15304e145f0c302b9fcc2c453900651/README.rst)):

```
case LWS_CALLBACK_RECEIVE:
{
    Client * const client = (Client *)user;
    const size_t remaining = libwebsockets_remaining_packet_payload(wsi);
    if (0 == remaining &&
        libwebsocket_is_final_fragment(wsi))
    {
        if (client->HasFragments())
        {
            client->AppendMessageFragment(in, len, 0);
            in = (void *)client->GetMessage();
            len = client->GetMessageLength();
        }

        client->ProcessMessage((char *)in, len, wsi);

        client->ResetMessage();
    }
    else
    {
        client->AppendMessageFragment(in, len, remaining);
    }
}
break;
```

My question is, what is the type Client? Which library/header should I add to my code?

Answer (score 0):

You're looking at an outdated README in an outdated fork of the project. Go to [the active project](https://github.com/warmcat/libwebsockets) or [visit the official page](https://libwebsockets.org).